# Removing an external component on click of button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I am new to React. I have the following components in the index.js React DOM area

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <NavigationBar />
    <App />
    <Login />
    
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The NavigationBar was created using Bootstrap and when I click on the search button, I wanted the  component to be removed and replaced by the  component.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use useState :
when you clicked on button you need to change the state with onChange

```
     const [check, setCheck] = useState(false);
    
        ReactDOM.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <NavigationBar />
        {check ? <App /> : anotherCoponent you want}
        <Login />
    
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```